# Create war file using maven with libraries from classpath intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to migrate an old project to maven. I want to create `.war` file via Maven

```xml
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>project</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

No dependencies yet, just build. I put all libraries into classpath in IntelliJ so I can see them in "External Libraries". When I use `mvn package`, I have an empty lib folder thus no libraries was copied there. Is there any further setup for Maven to put these libraries into necessary folder `WEB-INF/lib`?.

Comment: have you tried maven-war-plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Maven to copy the dependencies into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, you have to tell Maven about those dependencies: Maven is a tool independant of your IDE (whether it is Eclipse or IntelliJ) and so it will not look for the classpath you have configured in your IDE.

It actually works the other way around: IDE have plugins that will interact with the dependencies declared for Maven to update their classpaths accordingly (for Eclipse, this is the [M2Eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)).

Dependencies in Maven are declared in the POM, [by adding `<dependency>` tags to the `pom.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). Example of a dependency:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I am familiar with maven dependencies. But not all libraries are in global nexus and some of them are really old thus I need some of them have in path and force maven to use them also(next to libs defined via dependency).

Comment: @Milkmaid Then you need to [upload those artifacts](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading.html) to your Nexus manually.

Comment: I solve it this way. But still there must be some way. I think maven can simply copy some files from folder to folder. Perhaps that is the way.

Comment: @Milkmaid Maven will not read your IDE classpath, that's for sure. Uploading to your Nexus is the only correct way to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<dependencies>` section in your `pom.xml` - add a `<dependency>` entry for each library you need to use and let Maven resolve them. You only need to add those libraries you use, not their transitive dependencies - Maven will handle those for you.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html